# How to convert a gdb Value to a python numeral object while debugging C program

Tags: python, c, gdb, gdb-python

I'm using python2.6's gdb module while debugging a C program, and would like to convert a gdb.Value instance into a python numeral object (variable) based off the instance's '.Type'.

E.g. turn my C program's `SomeStruct->some_float_val = 1./6;` to a Python gdb.Value via `sfv=gdb.parse_and_eval('SomeStruct->some_double_val')`, but THEN turn this into a double precision floating point python variable -- knowing that `str(sfv.type.strip_typedefs())=='double'` and its size is 8B -- WITHOUT just converting through a string using `dbl=float(str(sfv))` or `Value.string()` but rather something like unpacking the bytes using `struct` to get the correct double value.

Every link returned from my searches points https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Values-From-Inferior.html#Values-From-Inferior, but I can't see how to convert a Value instance into a python variable cleanly, say the Value wasn't even in C memory but represented a gdb.Value.address (so can't use `Inferior.read_memory()`), how would one turn this into a Python int without casting string values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert it directly from the `Value` using `int` or `float`:

```
(gdb) python print int(gdb.Value(0))
0
(gdb) python print float(gdb.Value(0.0))
0.0
```

There seems to be at least one glitch in the system, though, as `float(gdb.Value(0))` does not work.

Comment: Thanks! This does appear to work on my C values but doesn't work all the time e.g. `int(xxxValue.address)` fails -- I have to use int(str()). Guess I'll have to catch exceptions. Unrelated, can you set a gdb.Value of a pointed to address to another gdb.Value or gdb.Parameter without using `gdb.parse_and_eval(xxx=newval)`?

Comment: I think you can convert a pointer using `long()`.  I don't think there is any way to assign right now without using `parse_and_eval`.

Comment: actually with python 2.7 you are better off using `long()` instead of int, as on the 32bit builds int will truncate the value to 32bits. As such I always use `long()`.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this while trying to figure out how to do bitwise operations on a pointer. In my particular use case, I needed to calculate a page alignment offset. Python did not want to cast a pointer Value to int, however, the following worked:

```
int(ptr.cast(gdb.lookup_type("unsigned long long")))
```

We first make gdb cast our pointer to unsigned long long, and then the resulting gdb.Value can be cast to Python int.