# Is there any way to access python object in gdb by given object address?

Tags: python, memory-management

For example, I know an address like '0x7f0fdd25d7d0' and it represents a python object with known python class type. Is there anyway to get the value of the fields of the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `gdb` documentation:

> You can use the command `x` (for "examine") to examine memory in any
>   of several formats, independently of your program's data types.

```
x/nfu addr
x addr
x
```

> Use the `x` command to examine memory.
>
> `n`, `f`, and `u` are all optional parameters that specify how much
>   memory to display and how to format it; `addr` is an expression giving
>   the address where you want to start displaying memory. If you use
>   defaults for `nfu`, you need not type the slash `/`. Several commands
>   set convenient defaults for addr.
>
> `n`, the repeat count
>
> The repeat count is a decimal integer; the default is 1. It specifies
>   how much memory (counting by units `u`) to display.
>
> `f`, the display format
>
> The display format is one of the formats used by print, `s`
>   (null-terminated string), or `i` (machine instruction). The default is
>   `x` (hexadecimal) initially. The default changes each time you use
>   either x or print.
>
> `u`, the unit size The unit size is any of
>
> `b` Bytes.
>
> `h` Halfwords (two bytes).
>
> `w` Words (four bytes). This is the initial default.
>
> `g` Giant words (eight bytes).
>
> Each time you specify a unit size with `x`, that size becomes the
>   default unit the next time you use `x`. (For the `s` and `i` formats,
>   the unit size is ignored and is normally not written.)
>
> `addr`, starting display address
>
> `addr` is the address where you want GDB to begin displaying memory.
>   The expression need not have a pointer value (though it may); it is
>   always interpreted as an integer address of a byte of memory. See
>   section Expressions, for more information on expressions. The default
>   for `addr` is usually just after the last address examined--but several
>   other commands also set the default address: info breakpoints (to the
>   address of the last breakpoint listed), info line (to the starting
>   address of a line), and print (if you use it to display a value from
>   memory). For example, `x/3uh 0x54320` is a request to display three
>   halfwords (`h`) of memory, formatted as unsigned decimal integers
>   (`u`), starting at address 0x54320. `x/4xw $sp` prints the four words
>   (`w`) of memory above the stack pointer (here, `$sp`; see section
>   Registers) in hexadecimal (`x`).
>
> Since the letters indicating unit sizes are all distinct from the
>   letters specifying output formats, you do not have to remember whether
>   unit size or format comes first; either order works. The output
>   specifications `4xw` and `4wx` mean exactly the same thing. (However,
>   the count n must come first; `wx4' does not work.)
>
> Even though the unit size u is ignored for the formats `s` and `i`,
>   you might still want to use a count n; for example, `3i` specifies
>   that you want to see three machine instructions, including any
>   operands. The command disassemble gives an alternative way of
>   inspecting machine instructions; see section Source and machine code.
>
> All the defaults for the arguments to x are designed to make it easy
>   to continue scanning memory with minimal specifications each time you
>   use x. For example, after you have inspected three machine
>   instructions with `x/3i addr`, you can inspect the next seven with
>   just `x/7`. If you use RET to repeat the x command, the repeat count n
>   is used again; the other arguments default as for successive uses of
>   x.
>
> The addresses and contents printed by the x command are not saved in
>   the value history because there is often too much of them and they
>   would get in the way. Instead, GDB makes these values available for
>   subsequent use in expressions as values of the convenience variables
>   $_ and $**. After an x command, the last address examined is available
>   for use in expressions in the convenience variable $_. The contents of
>   that address, as examined, are available in the convenience variable
>   $**.
>
> If the `x` command has a repeat count, the address and contents saved
>   are from the last memory unit printed; this is not the same as the
>   last address printed if several units were printed on the last line of
>   output.

**Source**: ftp://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_chapter/gdb_9.html#SEC56

More documentation on `gdb`:

> 23.2.2.4 Types In Python
>
> gdb represents types from the inferior using the class gdb.Type.
>
> The following type-related functions are available in the gdb module:
>
> — Function: **gdb.lookup_type (name [, block])** This function looks up a
>   type by its name, which must be a string.
>
> If block is given, then name is looked up in that scope. Otherwise, it
>   is searched for globally.
>
> Ordinarily, this function will return an instance of gdb.Type. If the
>   named type cannot be found, it will throw an exception.
>
> If the type is a structure or class type, or an enum type, the fields
>   of that type can be accessed using the Python dictionary syntax. For
>   example, if some_type is a gdb.Type instance holding a structure type,
>   you can access its foo field with:
>
> ```
>  bar = some_type['foo']
> ```
>
> bar will be a gdb.Field object; see below under the description of the Type.fields method for a description of
>   the gdb.Field class.
>
> An instance of Type has the following attributes:
>
> — Variable: **Type.code** The type code for this type. The type code will
>   be one of the TYPE_CODE_ constants defined below.
>
> — Variable: **Type.name** The name of this type. If this type has no name,
>   then None is returned.
>
> — Variable: **Type.sizeof** The size of this type, in target char units.
>   Usually, a target's char type will be an 8-bit byte. However, on some
>   unusual platforms, this type may have a different size.
>
> — Variable: **Type.tag** The tag name for this type. The tag name is the
>   name after struct, union, or enum in C and C++; not all languages have
>   this concept. If this type has no tag name, then None is returned.
>
> The following methods are provided:
>
> — Function: **Type.fields ()** For structure and union types, this method
>   returns the fields. Range types have two fields, the minimum and
>   maximum values. Enum types have one field per enum constant. Function
>   and method types have one field per parameter. The base types of C++
>   classes are also represented as fields. If the type has no fields, or
>   does not fit into one of these categories, an empty sequence will be
>   returned.
>
> Each field is a **gdb.Field** object, with some pre-defined attributes:
>
> bitpos This attribute is not available for enum or static (as in C++
>   or Java) fields. The value is the position, counting in bits, from the
>   start of the containing type.  enumval This attribute is only
>   available for enum fields, and its value is the enumeration member's
>   integer representation.  name The name of the field, or None for
>   anonymous fields.  artificial This is True if the field is artificial,
>   usually meaning that it was provided by the compiler and not the user.
>   This attribute is always provided, and is False if the field is not
>   artificial.  is_base_class This is True if the field represents a base
>   class of a C++ structure. This attribute is always provided, and is
>   False if the field is not a base class of the type that is the
>   argument of fields, or if that type was not a C++ class.  bitsize If
>   the field is packed, or is a bitfield, then this will have a non-zero
>   value, which is the size of the field in bits. Otherwise, this will be
>   zero; in this case the field's size is given by its type.  type The
>   type of the field. This is usually an instance of Type, but it can be
>   None in some situations.  parent_type The type which contains this
>   field. This is an instance of **gdb.Type**. — Function: **Type.array (n1 [,
>   n2])** Return a new gdb.Type object which represents an array of this
>   type. If one argument is given, it is the inclusive upper bound of the
>   array; in this case the lower bound is zero. If two arguments are
>   given, the first argument is the lower bound of the array, and the
>   second argument is the upper bound of the array. An array's length
>   must not be negative, but the bounds can be.
>
> — Function: **Type.vector (n1 [, n2])** Return a new **gdb.Type** object which
>   represents a vector of this type. If one argument is given, it is the
>   inclusive upper bound of the vector; in this case the lower bound is
>   zero. If two arguments are given, the first argument is the lower
>   bound of the vector, and the second argument is the upper bound of the
>   vector. A vector's length must not be negative, but the bounds can be.
>
> The difference between an array and a vector is that arrays behave
>   like in C: when used in expressions they decay to a pointer to the
>   first element whereas vectors are treated as first class values.
>
> — Function: **Type.const ()** Return a new **gdb.Type** object which
>   represents a const-qualified variant of this type.
>
> — Function: **Type.volatile ()** Return a new **gdb.Type** object which
>   represents a volatile-qualified variant of this type.
>
> — Function: **Type.unqualified ()** Return a new **gdb.Type** object which
>   represents an unqualified variant of this type. That is, the result is
>   neither const nor volatile.
>
> — Function: **Type.range ()** Return a Python Tuple object that contains
>   two elements: the low bound of the argument type and the high bound of
>   that type. If the type does not have a range, gdb will raise a
>   gdb.error exception (see Exception Handling).
>
> — Function: **Type.reference ()** Return a new **gdb.Type** object which
>   represents a reference to this type.
>
> — Function: **Type.pointer ()** Return a new **gdb.Type** object which
>   represents a pointer to this type.
>
> — Function: **Type.strip_typedefs ()** Return a new **gdb.Type** that
>   represents the real type, after removing all layers of typedefs.
>
> — Function: **Type.target ()** Return a new **gdb.Type** object which
>   represents the target type of this type.
>
> For a pointer type, the target type is the type of the pointed-to
>   object. For an array type (meaning C-like arrays), the target type is
>   the type of the elements of the array. For a function or method type,
>   the target type is the type of the return value. For a complex type,
>   the target type is the type of the elements. For a typedef, the target
>   type is the aliased type.
>
> If the type does not have a target, this method will throw an
>   exception.
>
> — Function: **Type.template_argument** (n [, block]) If this **gdb.Type** is
>   an instantiation of a template, this will return a new gdb.Value or
>   **gdb.Type** which represents the value of the nth template argument
>   (indexed starting at 0).
>
> If this **gdb.Type** is not a template type, or if the type has fewer than
>   n template arguments, this will throw an exception. Ordinarily, only
>   C++ code will have template types.
>
> If block is given, then name is looked up in that scope. Otherwise, it
>   is searched for globally.
>
> — Function: **Type.optimized_out ()** Return gdb.Value instance of this
>   type whose value is optimized out. This allows a frame decorator to
>   indicate that the value of an argument or a local variable is not
>   known.
>
> Each type has a code, which indicates what category this type falls
>   into. The available type categories are represented by constants
>   defined in the gdb module:
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_PTR** The type is a pointer.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_ARRAY** The type is an array.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_STRUCT** The type is a structure.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_UNION** The type is a union.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_ENUM** The type is an enum.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_FLAGS** A bit flags type, used for things such as status
>   registers.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_FUNC** The type is a function.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_INT** The type is an integer type.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_FLT** A floating point type.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_VOID** The special type void.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_SET** A Pascal set type.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_RANGE** A range type, that is, an integer type with
>   bounds.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_STRING** A string type. Note that this is only used for
>   certain languages with language-defined string types; C strings are
>   not represented this way.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_BITSTRING** A string of bits. It is deprecated.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_ERROR** An unknown or erroneous type.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_METHOD** A method type, as found in C++ or Java.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_METHODPTR** A pointer-to-member-function.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_MEMBERPTR** A pointer-to-member.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_REF** A reference type.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_CHAR** A character type.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_BOOL** A boolean type.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_COMPLEX** A complex float type.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_TYPEDEF** A typedef to some other type.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_NAMESPACE** A C++ namespace.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_DECFLOAT** A decimal floating point type.
>
> **gdb.TYPE_CODE_INTERNAL_FUNCTION** A function internal to gdb. This is
>   the type used to represent convenience functions. Further support for
>   types is provided in the gdb.types Python module (see gdb.types).

**Source**: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Types-In-Python.html

Related:

- https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/gdb_002etypes.html#gdb_002etypes
- [Find out how much memory is being used by an object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33978/find-out-how-much-memory-is-being-used-by-an-object-in-python)
- [How do I determine the size of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python)
- [Can GDB print the size of structures from a core dump of a C program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645027/can-gdb-print-the-size-of-structures-from-a-core-dump-of-a-c-program)
- [How to convert a gdb Value to a python numeral object while debugging C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932049/how-to-convert-a-gdb-value-to-a-python-numeral-object-while-debugging-c-program)